# Exceptions works correct but not how its must

Tags: java, exception, ioexception, throw, throws

1. The method `processExceptions`() should call the method `BEAN.methodThrowExceptions` and handle exceptions:

1.1. if an exception `FileSystemException` occurs, then log it by calling the method `BEAN.log` and throw forward

1.2. if an exception `CharConversionException` or any other `IOException` occurs, just log it by calling the method `BEAN.log`

2. Add the class/type of the exception you are forwarding  in 2.1. to the `processExceptions()` method signature.
3. Handle the remaining exception in the method `main()` and log it. Use `try..catch`

I tried different solutions. It works but not as it should. What is the correct placement of `throws` in methods. Or maybe i shouldnt use them at all? And if I don't place them I can't make use of `throw`. Please help, I would really appreciate your time.

```
public class Solution {

    public static StatelessBean BEAN = new StatelessBean();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            processExceptions();
        }
        catch (CharConversionException e){
            BEAN.log(e);
        }
    }


    public static void processExceptions()throws CharConversionException {
        try{
            BEAN.methodThrowExceptions();
        }
        catch (CharConversionException e){
            BEAN.log(e);
            throw e;
        }
        catch (FileSystemException e){
            BEAN.log(e);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            BEAN.log(e);
        }
    }

    public static class StatelessBean {
        public void log(Exception exception) {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage() + ", " + exception.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }

        public void methodThrowExceptions() throws CharConversionException, FileSystemException, IOException {
            int i = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
            if (i == 0)
                throw new CharConversionException();
            if (i == 1)
                throw new FileSystemException("");
            if (i == 2)
                throw new IOException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a correct rendition of the requirements; however the requirements themselves are broken: either re-throw *or* log, never both. Also, if `FileSystemException extends IOException`, then catching it explicitly is redundant because the catch-blocks are the same.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work as it should, what is the exact problem with it?

Comment: you mean that i cant use throws and log in one try-catch block?

Comment: @Predict_it you can. It's just bad style.

Answer (score 0):

If a method is capable of throwing an exception which IS NOT RuntimeException (either directly throwing or invoking a method which can throw an exception), it should either handle the exception or declare that it throws the exception, so that any other method which calls this method would know that it can encounter an exception and can either handle it or declare it that it throws (and so on).

Since you are dealing with checked exception, there is no clean way to avoid declaring throws, but there is a (messy) workaround. You can wrap the exception in a RuntimeException and can throw it and when you want to handle it, you can get the actual exception from the re.getCause();

```
public class Solution {

    public static StatelessBean BEAN = new StatelessBean();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            processExceptions();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException re){
            if (!(re.getCause() instanceof CharConversationException)) {
                //handle the case in which the exception was not CCE and not FSE not IOException
            }
        }
    }


    public static void processExceptions() {
        try{
            BEAN.methodThrowExceptions();
        } catch (CharConversionException cce){
            BEAN.log(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(cce);
        } catch (FileSystemException fse){
            BEAN.log(e);
        } catch (IOException e){
            BEAN.log(e);
        }
    }

    public static class StatelessBean {
        public void log(Exception exception) {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage() + ", " + exception.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }

        public void methodThrowExceptions() throws CharConversionException, FileSystemException, IOException {
            int i = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
            if (i == 0)
                throw new CharConversionException();
            if (i == 1)
                throw new FileSystemException("");
            if (i == 2)
                throw new IOException();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether I understood your question correctly and this is what you wanted :)

Comment: i dont understand =(, why should i use runtimeexception

Answer (score 0):

I think that the order:

> Handle the **remaining** exception in the method main()

means that you should catch not only `CharConversionException`, but all other Exceptions by:

```
catch (Exception e)
```

Besides, you should ask it on [help.javarush.net](http://help.javarush.net) I think :>